# Подскажите пожалуйста: почему картинка занимает всю строку, а теги <p> переходят на новую строку?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.mainDecription {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'logoInDescription textInDescription';
  grid-template-columns: 500px 600px;
}

.logoInDescription {
  grid-area: 'logoInDescription';
}

.textInDescription {
  grid-area: 'textInDescription';
}

#logoInDescriptionId {
  height: 500px;
}

#headerOfTextInDesc {}

#mainOfTextInDesc {}
```

```html
<div class="mainDescription">
  <div class="logoInDescription">
    <img src="zvezda.jpg" alt="" id="logoInDescriptionId">
  </div>
  <div class="textInDescription">
    <p id="headerOfTextInDesc">какой-то текст, какой-то текст!</p>
    <p id="mainOfTextInDesc">какой-то текст, какой-то текст! какой-то текст, какой-то текст! какой-то текст, какой-то текст! какой-то текст, какой-то текст! какой-то текст, какой-то текст!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: С чего бы начать? Может с того, что у вас в HTML лежит класс ".mainDesription" а в CSS ".mainDecription". Не видите разницы? А я вижу — "s". А за то, что вы в CSS вместо классов безо всякой на то необходимости пытаетесь стилизовать элементы через айдишники # нужно бить по рукам. Понятия не имею что у вас там ещё безо всякого на то смысла налеплено, но c учётом отутствия стилизации соразмерности изображений дальше будет что угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так работает:

```css
.mainDescription {
  grid-template-areas: 'logoInDescription textInDescription';
  grid-template-columns: 500px 600px;
}

.logoInDescription {
  grid-area: 'logoInDescription';
  display: inline-block;
}

.textInDescription {
  grid-area: 'textInDescription';
  display: inline-block;
}

#logoInDescriptionId {
  height: 500px;
}

#headerOfTextInDesc {}

#mainOfTextInDesc {}
```

```html
<div class="mainDescription">
  <div class="logoInDescription">
    <img src="zvezda.jpg" alt="" id="logoInDescriptionId">
  </div>
  <div class="textInDescription">
    <p id="headerOfTextInDesc">какой-то текст, какой-то текст!</p>
    <p id="mainOfTextInDesc">какой-то текст, какой-то текст! какой-то текст, какой-то текст! какой-то текст, какой-то текст! какой-то текст, какой-то текст! какой-то текст, какой-то текст!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: И здесь class="mainDescription" и стиль к нему  .mainDecription Это будет работать? Что-то сомневаюсь ))

Comment: Прежде чем опубликовать свой код, я прочитал Ваш комментарий про неверное наименование класса и изменил его, затем проверил и только потом выложил код. Процитировал код автора, для ускорения ответа, отсюда и ошибка в наименовании - уже исправил))